# Appreciate help on a problem with the sum of squared combinations picked from a factorial.

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, factorial

As part of working on a problem, I have encountered the following:

From $\frac{n!}{2!}$, I have to pick $k$ combinations of subfactorials and then sum their squares. The number of combinations will be ${n-2 \choose k}, k=1,2,3...$ I am interested in series for simultaneously increasing $n$ ($>2)$ and $k$, i.e. the next one in the series is ${n+1-2 \choose k+1}$ combinations out of $\frac{(n+1)!}{2!}$.

**Example:**

$n=5$, so choose from $5\cdot4\cdot3$:

- all combinations of length $1$. This gives a sum of ${3 \choose 1}=3$ squared combinations:

$$\scriptsize 5^2+ 4^2+ 3^2=50$$

$n=6$, so choose from $6\cdot5\cdot4\cdot3$:

- all combinations of length $2$. This gives a sum of ${4 \choose 2}=6$ squared combinations:

$$\scriptsize (6\cdot5)^2+ (6\cdot4)^2+ (6\cdot3)^2+ (5\cdot4)^2+ (5\cdot3)^2+(4\cdot3)^2=2569$$

$n=7$, so choose from $7\cdot6\cdot5\cdot4 \cdot 3$:

- all combinations of length $3$. This gives a sum of ${5 \choose 3}=10$ squared combinations:

$$\scriptsize (7\cdot6\cdot5)^2+ (7\cdot6\cdot4)^2+ (7\cdot6\cdot3)^2+ (7\cdot5\cdot4)^2+ (7\cdot5\cdot3)^2+ (7\cdot4\cdot3)^2+ (6\cdot5\cdot4)^2+ (6\cdot5\cdot3)^2+ (6\cdot4\cdot3)^2+ (5\cdot4\cdot3)^2=157165$$

Etc.

Things are getting complex rather quickly and Sloane's integer sequences didn't reveal any clue.

Could a closed form for such a problem exist?

Thanks!

Comment: Well, if I have understood the definition (not clear), then letting $F(n,k)$ denote the answer, it looks like $F(n,k)=F(n-1,k)+F(n-1,k-1)\times n^2$.  That should at least facilitate computations.

Comment: @lulu, thanks for your swift response. I found the same recursive formula as well and even have a closed form for $F(n,1)$. From there I can "generate" with the recursive formula all $F(n,k)$s and store the values in e.g. an array. The disadvantage of this method that I have to set a max $n,k$ and can't make it truly generic. Looking 'top down', I then found that each $F(n,k)$ can be expressed as a weighted combination of the $F(x,1)$s, $x=2..n-1$ and these weights are exactly the ones in the series listed in my question. Let me know how I can clarify further!

Comment: By elementary algebra, $F(n,k)$ is the coefficient of $x^k$ in $\prod_{p=3}^n\ 1+p^2x$. That product can be expressed as $\frac{x^n(1-i/\sqrt{x})_n(1+i/\sqrt{x})_n}{4x^2+5x+1}$ where $()_n$ means the rising factorial.

Comment: Many thanks, Andrew. That works perfectly and I can see all the numbers (as coefficients) I was looking for :-)